# how to use GWT suggest box with RPC?

Tags: gwt

but in specific requirement, i want use suggest box provided by GWT. i cannot get all strings from DB and store in suggest box, as it has 16000 records. so my requirement is as and when user enters 3 charaters i need get the string that matches 3 chars(like search). please suggest me how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Implement your own [`SuggestOracle`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestOracle.html) that, when asked for suggestions, makes an asynchronous server call instead of matching against an in-memory set of strings:

```
public class MySuggestOracle extends SuggestOracle {
  public void requestSuggestions(SuggestOracle.Request suggestRequest,
                                 final SuggestOracle.Callback callback)
  {
    RequestBuilder rb =
      new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET,
                         "/suggestions?" + suggestRequest.getQuery());
    rb.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
        // Handle error
      }

      @Override
      public void onResponseReceived(Request rbRequest, Response response) {
        SuggestOracle.Response r = new SuggestOracle.Response();

        // Fill r based on suggestions in the response parameter.

        callback.onSuggestionsReady(suggestRequest, r);
      }
    });
}
```